# Как проверить, загружено ли изображение?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Перед загрузкой изображения вывожу DIV, и после загрузки картинки DIV скрываю.

```
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function() {
    $(".hide").show();  
};
img.src = "http://...";
```

Как исключить повторную загрузку изображения, проверяя, загружено ли уже изображение?

Comment: а почему бы вам его не загрузить в Base64?

Comment: а где вы ожидаете повтор ? если изображение в кэше то загрузки второй раз не будет. Кроме того у Image есть свойство complete, которое выставляется в true, сразу после задания src, если изображение уже загружено.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам интересно не выполнять onload, в случае, когда изображение было в кэше или загружено ранее, то используйте HTMLImageElement.complete

```js
jQuery(function($) { // jQuery для простоты примера
  var images = ['100x100', '100x100', '100x200', '', '100x100?' + Math.random()];

  images.forEach(showImage);

  function showImage(imgName) {
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.onload = imgLoaded.bind(this, image, 'было загружено');
    image.onerror = imgLoaded.bind(this, image, 'получили ошибку');
    image.src = '//dummyimage.com/' + imgName;
    if (image.complete) {
      image.onload = null;
      image.onerror = null;
      imgLoaded(image,'уже загружено')
    }
  }

  function imgLoaded(image, message) {
    $('body').append(image);
    $(image).after('<div>' + message + '</div>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```